# Display date from sql database in this format: Friday, 10th May,2019

Tags: php, sql, date

A column called `st_date` in my SQL table contains data in this form : **2019-05-10 00:00:00**

Is there a query I can write to manipulate it and display it as :
**Friday, 10th May 2019**.

I have tried `CAST(st_date AS Date)`. It didn't give me that.
Have also tried `FORMAT`.

I expect the date to be displayed as **Friday, 10th May,2019**.
I am using PHP with SQL.

Comment: The answer is "yes"; almost all databases have the ability to format dates as strings.  However, the exact syntax tends to be database-dependent.  So, you should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You will get all your wish from this [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date_format/).

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2019-05-10 00:00:00', '%W, %D %M %Y') cust_date
```

Comment: How do you know that OP uses MySQL?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I will wait for OP’s objection.